# Crystal Reports Compatibility issue

Tags: crystal-reports

i am using Crystal Reports with visual Studio 2012, but it does not work properly,
i think it will compatibility issue, which version of Crystal Reports will use with Visual Studio 2012, if u have any idea please help me

Comment: My Crystal Report Version is: CRforVS_13_0_7

Answer (score 0):

CR13 is for VS2010 -VS2013. So you are using the right version. What kind of issues do you have ?